# Issues accessing webpage even with Port Forwarding enabled on PPPoE WAN

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, ddns

I have gone through a bunch of similar questions here and other forums but none of them exactly fit my scenario.

I have checked on http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and it reports `103.XXX.YY.ZZ` as my IP address.

What I am trying to do is access my home webserver (Ip: `192.168.1.17`, port `8080`) over the internet and I know for doing this my router should forward incoming Ports From WAN to LAN. I have already configured this on my router. However even after doing so, I wasn't able to access the web server on `103.XXX.YY.ZZ:8080` from the browser. The connection times out.

WAN info from my home router's (Ip: `192.168.1.1`) Configuration page is:

```
WAN IP Address:        172.16.50.155
WAN Netmask:           255.255.255.255
WAN MAC Address:       44:32:F5:25:2J:2K
WAN Gateway IP:        103.246.240.154
WAN DNS Server(s):     103.246.240.19
                       8.8.8.8
WAN (PPPoE) Uptime:    0 days, 0 hours, 24 minutes
```

The home router connects to the internet using PPPoE connection, info about *pppoe-wan* interface on my home router (Ip: `192.168.1.1`):

```
pppoe-wan Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol                                                                                                           
          inet addr:172.16.59.177  P-t-P:103.246.240.154  Mask:255.255.255.255                                                                         
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1480  Metric:1                                                                                   
          RX packets:6879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                        
          TX packets:6185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                      
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3                                                                                                                    
          RX bytes:7038141 (6.7 MiB)  TX bytes:691150 (674.9 KiB)
```

The *traceroute* output from my home web server (Ip: `192.168.1.17`) to www.google.com:

```
traceroute to www.google.com (216.58.196.68), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.955 ms  1.023 ms  1.322 ms
 2  103.246.240.154.soipl.co.in (103.246.240.154)  7.294 ms  7.385 ms  7.472 ms
 3  * * *
 4  103.246.240.49.soipl.co.in (103.246.240.49)  9.412 ms  9.403 ms  9.448 ms
 5  100.100.20.5 (100.100.20.5)  7.477 ms  7.617 ms  9.396 ms
 6  103.246.240.174.soipl.co.in (103.246.240.174)  8.807 ms  1.806 ms  5.329 ms
 7  103.246.240.173.soipl.co.in (103.246.240.173)  5.531 ms  5.782 ms  7.893 ms
 8  103.246.240.201.soipl.co.in (103.246.240.201)  7.997 ms  10.446 ms  10.439 ms
 9  108.170.248.177 (108.170.248.177)  7.024 ms  7.240 ms  7.488 ms
10  209.85.255.207 (209.85.255.207)  10.553 ms  10.802 ms 209.85.255.209 (209.85.255.209)  5.406 ms
11  kul01s09-in-f68.1e100.net (216.58.196.68)  4.210 ms  4.575 ms  5.280 ms
```

***The `103.XXX.YY.ZZ` is to be seen nowhere.*** When I open `103.XXX.YY.ZZ:8080`, it errors out.
However from my home network if I open `192.168.1.17:8080` or even `172.16.50.155:8080`, the page loads as expected.

Since `172.16.50.155:8080` is working I can confidently say that the port forwarding setting o my router is on. But id doesn't see my `103.XXX.YY.ZZ` as my public address.

**Clearly, my Public IP is different from the WAN IP on my router.**

What I have tried so far:

1. verified all the Ip addresses and ports numerous times
2. tried different address / ports
3. tried with firewall disabled completely on the router as well as the web server

Nothing works.
This has made me to suspect that i might be facing the [Double-NAT](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3175739/network-router/how-to-identify-and-resolve-double-nat-problems.html) issue but I am not entirely sure because the second hop in the *traceroute* output doesn't seem to be a private IP.

Things to note:

- I do not have access to my ISP's router neither they are going to enable port forwarding on their router in case of double-NAT.
- This is the only ISP in my location.

**Can someone please point me in the right direction and how can I get this working? Will a VPN setup make any difference?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What likely happens is that your ISP does carrier grade NAT (there aren't enough IPv4 addresses left), so you need port forwarding not only in your router, but also in your ISP's routers which do the NAT. Which is not going to happen, because you didn't pay your ISP for it.

Options:

- Use IPv6 (and hope your ISP doesn't NAT those, too - some ISP's do).
- Find another ISP which doesn't do carrier-grade NAT.
- Pay your ISP to have a public IPv4 address.
- Pay someone else to have a public IPv4 address (usually by renting a server). Then you can either run the webserver there, or tunnel it via VPN or otherwise to your homeserver.

VPN services (where you don't pay for the server, just for the connection) also do NAT, so just getting a VPN won't help, either.

Comment: I do not have access to my ISP's router neither they are going to do this for me. Any other options? Also there are no other ISPs in my location. They also don't support IPv6

Comment: These leaves the option "rent a server" as the only option.